# ICC in Random intercept model with a predictor variable

Tags: mixed-model, intercept, intraclass-correlation

Are we able/ or is it correct to calculate ICC in random intercept model which has a preditor variable within?

Does this value give us the variation of the outcome which is purely related to subject heterogeneity?